# Loop - Select row, find value, replace value

Tags: excel, vba

How can I loop this?

this is currently selecting row 4. Finding the value in AO4, and replacing the value in AQ4.
How can i loop this until the end of the sheet? Based on data in column E

next would be select row 5, find value in AO5, replace with value in AQ5

VBA Code:

```
Rows(4).Select
    Cells.Replace What:=range("AO4").Value, Replacement:=range("AQ4").Value, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
        :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=True, _
        FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
```

Comment: In which range should the replacement happen? `Cells` refers to all worksheet cells `1:1048576` including the cells in column `AO`. Are there two worksheets?

Answer (score 0):

With a `For Each` loop:

```
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row

Dim cell As Range
For Each cell in Range("AO4:AO" & lastRow)
    Cells.Replace What:=cell.Value, Replacement:=Range("AQ" & cell.Row).Value '....
Next
```